# Using the ScrollableTabRow I create the tabs But I want to know how to navigate to each page

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

With the drawerContent I navigate between functions
Using the ScrollableTabRow I create the tabs But I want to know how to navigate to each page......

MY Code:

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableTabRowDemo() {
    val state = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val titles = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
    Column {
        ScrollableTabRow(
                selectedTabIndex = state.value,
                modifier = Modifier.wrapContentWidth(),
                edgePadding = 16.dp
        ) {
            titles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(
                        text = { Text(title) },
                        selected = state.value == index,
                        onClick = { state.value = index }
                )
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Text(
                modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally),
                text = "${state.value + 1}",
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean my navigate to each page? using your code you can navigate by selecting needed tab

Answer (score 0):

it worked

```
@Composable
fun ScrollableTabRowDemo() {
    val state = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val titles = listOf("Home", "Cadastro")

    Column {
        ViewPagerScreen()

        ScrollableTabRow(
                selectedTabIndex = state.value,
                backgroundColor= colorResource(id = R.color.green),
            modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentWidth()
                ,indicator = { tabPositions ->
            TabRowDefaults.Indicator(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    height = 4.dp,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .tabIndicatorOffset(tabPositions[state.value])
            )

        }

        ) {
            titles.forEachIndexed { index, title ->
                Tab(
                        text = { Text(title,color = Color.White) },
                        selected = state.value == index,
                        onClick = { state.value = index },
                        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)


                )
            }
        }

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))

        Column() {
            if(state.value==0){
                RecyclerView()
            }else{
                Form()
            }
        }

    }
}
```